# Programmatically Centre UIImageVIew Using Auto Layout After Resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have only ever used auto layout in IB and was wondering how I can go about programatically setting a UIImageView to centre both vertically and horizontally after resizing it.

Basically the UIImageView contains a photo and the UIImageView is then resized to fit the photo. After this process I was wondering how I can go about setting the constraints so that the image is correctly positioned.

The code below shows the process of loading the image and setting the UIImageView. At the minute the positioning is done manually without the use of AutoLayout.

```
- (void)setupUI {

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

self.imageViewCanvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[self.imageViewCanvas setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

self.btnTool.alpha = 0;

}

- (void)loadNewImageIntoCanvas {

[self.imageViewCanvas setImage:self.imageToEdit];

[self imageSizeAfterAspectFit:self.imageViewCanvas];

[UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    self.imageViewCanvas.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [self showBTNTool];

}];


}

- (void)resetCanvasSize {

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

[self.imageViewCanvas setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

}

-(CGSize)imageSizeAfterAspectFit:(UIImageView*)imgview{

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

CGRect newSize = [self frameForImage:self.imageViewCanvas.image inImageViewAspectFit:self.imageViewCanvas];

float newwidth = newSize.size.width;
float newheight = newSize.size.height;

float new_x = (screenWidth / 2) - (newwidth / 2);
float new_y = (screenHeight / 2) - (newheight / 2);

[self.imageViewCanvas setFrame:CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, newwidth, newheight)];

return CGSizeMake(0, 0);

}

-(CGRect)frameForImage:(UIImage*)image inImageViewAspectFit:(UIImageView*)imageView {

float imageRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;

float viewRatio = imageView.frame.size.width / imageView.frame.size.height;

if(imageRatio < viewRatio)
{
    float scale = imageView.frame.size.height / image.size.height;

    float width = scale * image.size.width;

    float topLeftX = (imageView.frame.size.width - width) * 0.5;

    return CGRectMake(topLeftX, 0, width, imageView.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
    float scale = imageView.frame.size.width / image.size.width;

    float height = scale * image.size.height;

    float topLeftY = (imageView.frame.size.height - height) * 0.5;

    return CGRectMake(0, topLeftY, imageView.frame.size.width, height);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just say self.imageViewCanvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; then set it's frame?

Comment: I am doing that now but I get warning messages when I run the app. Along the lines of "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." Updated question to show how I do this.

Comment: With the result being that the image is not in the right place?

Comment: No the image is in the correct place, I was looking at switching this over so I can let AutoLayout manage the positioning after resizing the image.

Comment: Do you have complex interface that requires dependent positioning? Auto layout seems like over kill for what you're doing. Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true cause the auto layout engine to create constraints, sometime conflicting, but it knows which ones to break to place the element in its proper frame.

Comment: I do have a reasonably complex layout. There are a lot of sub options "UIViews" that fade in and out depending upon what tools and features are selected.

Comment: Then shouldn't you use IB?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try to do this using IB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to center image view using auto layout you need constraints for width and height too. Not only centerXAnchor and centerYAnchor.
Because `UIImageView` doesn't have intrinsicContentSize.

(Note that `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` methods are only available on iOS 9.0+)

```
self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.imageView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
[self.imageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = YES;

[self.imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.imageWidth].active = YES;
[self.imageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.imageHeight].active = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can say something like this.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageViewCanvas attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageViewCanvas attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

This is not enough to satisfy all the necessary constraints though. IMO, it's easier to set constraints in IB, if you need to dynamically change the constraints, create an IBOutlet for them, and change their constant property.

For example, you can create one IBOutlet for your image view's height constraint, call it imageViewHeightConstraint, another for your image view's width constraint, call it imageViewWidthConstraint, then you can say:

```
self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400;
self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = 400;
```

Comment: Is the constant property the size? So if I change it so that the new UIImageView is lets say 400 x 400 the constant would be 400?